# Swift 4: Local Dependencies with Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift, linux, dependencies, swift-package-manager

I'm in the process of porting a fairly large codebase from Java to server-side Swift 4.  The code itself will be developed on macOS, but eventually deployed on Linux.  I have created separate module projects using the Swift Package Manager.  Several of these are library projects, with the final being an executable to tie them all together to launch.  I've generated Xcode project files for each module so that I can easily develop in Xcode, and I've created an Xcode Workspace to group them all together into one view.

My problem is, how do I indicate dependencies between these local modules?  My executable module will obviously depend on all of the library modules.  How do I represent this in my `Package.swift` file?  I've tried something like this...

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MySwiftExe",
    dependencies: [
        //.package(url: "../MySwiftLib", from: "1.0.0"),

...
```

But that fails to build.  Is there a way to specify dependencies located on the same filesystem?  Or am I ***required*** to grab the dependencies from Git?

Answer (score 4):

Your URL can be relative, so `../MySwiftLib` is perfectly valid. However, the source directory must be a git repository. It is recommended that this repo be tagged, but you can also do:

`.package(url: "../MySwiftLib", .branch("master"))`

if you want to use whatever code is on the `master` branch.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you show your Package.swift and Info.plist for the library you're loading into some project? And the Package.swift for the thing loading the library. I am not able to get this to work. Getting `error: no such module foo`.

Comment: @LancePollard There are examples available on swift.org, such as this page: https://swift.org/package-manager/

Comment: You just need to change the URL to a relative URL or `file://` URL

Answer (score 2):

Set the url value to `file:///path/to/swiftlib`:

```
let package = Package(
name: "MySwiftExe",
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "file:///path/to/MySwiftLib", from: "1.0.0"),

...
```

Comment: Can I use a relative path? Or does it have to be absolute?

Comment: It must be absolute at this time. However, I did find this recently accepted proposal: [SE-0201: Package Manager Local Dependencies](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0201-package-manager-local-dependencies.md). It appears to change this in the future.

Comment: And I see it has to be a git repo, as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, it must also be a git repo.

Comment: You can use relative paths in this way (without the `file` scheme in the url):  `.package(url: "../MySwiftLib", from: "1.0.0")`. Note that the dependency package still has to be a git repository (local), with a tag. The non-tagged changed in the local dependencies will not be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html#package-dependency) there's the `package(path: String)` function that can be used to define a local dependency.

One thing to mention is that in case the package provides multiple targets and your project is configured to only use some of those targets:

```
...
dependencies: [
    .package(name: "MyPackage", url: "git@github.com:path/to/package.git", .exact("ver.si.on")),
]
...
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MyTarget",
        dependencies: [
            .product(name: "SpecificTargetName", package: "MyPackage"),
        ],
    ),
]
```

Then for that to work locally the package definition deeds to declare the name as well (the path is not enough):

```
.package(name: "MyPackage", path: "/local/path/to/package"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that you have the following folder structure:

```
    ├──MySwiftExe/
    |  ├──Sources/
    |  |  ├──MySwiftExe.swift
    ├──Modules/
       ├──MySwiftLib/
          └──Sources/
             └──MySwiftLib.swift
```

The Swift Package Manager allows us to use relative paths for integrating dependencies, as shown below:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MySwiftExe",
    dependencies: [
        .package(path: "../Modules/MySwiftLib"),
    ]
)
```